# How to unhash the password which is hashed by generate_password_hash?

Tags: python, flask, md5

I am using `Flask` to develop a small web service, the user password is stored in mysql after using `generate_password_hash`.
just like: password = "123345", the stored value in mysql is `generate_password_hash(12345)`.

Not i want implement the function for look back my password, but i meet an issue when unhash the stored password.

just how convert `generate_password_hash(12345)` to `12345`?

Comment: The point of password hashing is specifically to prevent anyone from doing this.

Comment: @user2357112 So how to design the function for get back my password?

Comment: You don't. If you're trying to validate login attempts, you check whether the user-supplied password matches the hash. If you're trying to implement a password recovery feature, implement a password reset feature instead.

Comment: Also, if you're actually using MD5 for this, stop. I think you would have had to specifically tell `generate_password_hash` to use MD5; assuming it's [this thing](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/utils/#werkzeug.security.generate_password_hash), it should default to PBKDF2 with SHA1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function):

> [MD5] is a mathematical algorithm that maps data of arbitrary size to a bit string of a fixed size (a hash function) which is designed to also be a **one-way function**, that is, **a function which is infeasible to invert**.

Leaving aside potential vulnerabilities, there's no way to get the original data that produced the hash. And that's the idea. If some bad guy get access to your database, he won't be able to know your users' passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Unhashing passwords is meant to be very difficult, otherwise there would be no value in the hashing process, and you could just store plain passwords in the database.

That being said, there are unhashing programs out there that take a lot of processor power, and run for a long time, that can unhash very simple passwords.

If you wanted to make you own very simple (and very inefficient) unhasher, you would need to basically pass every possible password through the generate_password_hash function until you find one that generates the same hash. Basically starting with all single character passwords, then going to 2 character passwords, etc. There is a lot written about how to do this more efficiently online.